# Testing react component

Tags: reactjs, ajax

I have a simple app where I use an axios to get UserList from the API.
Here is my App component:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import UserList from './components/Users/UserList';


function App() {

const [users,setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
  .then(response =>{
      setUsers(response.data.data);
      console.log(response.data);
      
      
  })
  .catch(error =>{
    console.log(error)
  })
}, [])

  

  return (
    <div>
      
      <UserList users={users} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And I have the UserList component:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './UserList.module.css';
import Card from '../UI/Card';

const UserList = (props) => {




    return (
        <Card className={classes.users}>
            <ul data-testid="ultest">
                {props.users.map(user => <li key={user.id}>
                    <img src={user.avatar} alt={user.id}></img>
                    <div>{user.first_name}  {user.last_name}
                        <p><a href={`mailto:${user.email}`}>{user.email}</a></p>
                    </div>
                </li>)}
            </ul>

        </Card>
    )
}

export default UserList;
```

I don't understand how to test UserList component. I want to test if it renders correctly but I always get:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
When I use render.
What is the best way to test this component? Jest or testing library.
Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render} from '@testing-library/react';

import UserList from '../components/Users/UserList';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';




test('to check if it renders', () => {
    
    
       render (<UserList />)
      
    
      
      
    
    
  });
```

Comment: You're rendering it without any props, where _is_ `users` supposed to come from? And how is the parent relevant?

Comment: That was my question. How to add users to this testing component. Sorry if the question is not formatted well. When i use {...props} it shows an error

Comment: Well how do you normally pass props to a component when you render it? It's no different in a test.

Comment: The component under test still needs all the props it expects to receive, i.e. something like `render (<UserList users={......} />)`.

Comment: Well, I am trying but it shows an error. "est encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Comment: Errors seem like very relevant information when asking for help with code you wrote. can you update your question to include all relevant details and error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Hey – You need to do it like so:

```
test('to check if it renders', () => {    
    render(<UserList users={someUsersDataHere}/>)
});
```

So your component can have users to map over. You will need to manually define some array of users or import the data from elsewhere if you have it already by any chance

```
const someUsersDataHere = [
   {name: 'SomeName'},
   ....and so on
]
```

Comment: Should I use fake data or can I use data that I get from an axios call? When I try to pass on props i get an error ======= est encountered an unexpected token This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript. By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules"

Comment: Fake data is what you'll use. Making server requests is not ideal for tests

Comment: Thank you  dear. For someone that has been learning React for a week, testing is difficult. Now everything works with fake data. Thank you <3

Comment: Nice!  All the best

Comment: If you are simply testing that it renders then the easiest thing to do is pass an empty array, since that is all the component really needs. The minimal amount `render(<UserList users={[]}/>)`.

Comment: Best to test with the full thing i.e. at least one data point. Seen cases where passing an empty array like so could give false positives  doesn't really cost much to give the data point but it could potentially save you some

Comment: That is what any additional unit tests are for beyond a "does it render and not crash" basic test. 

Comment: Gotcha! I totally understand what you're saying, but I think rendering correctly constitutes checking that your `.map` runs correctly and doesn't break too. Imagine you had some logic in the map function and a colleague(through no fault of theirs) refactors a little. It can be especially dangerous and can throw a false positive without data. What do you think?